# jQuery Dirtyforms - Is it possible to use the native browser confirm() as dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-dirtyforms

The examples in their [site](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms) usually assumes that a jquery dialog is used such as facebox or jquery-ui. Is it possible to use the native browser confirm() as dialog? If so, is there a way to bind the ok and cancel buttons?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how elegant this is, but I solved it by doing this:

```
$('form').dirtyForms();
$.DirtyForms.debug = true;
$.DirtyForms.dialog = {
    fire: function (message, title) {
        $.DirtyForms.choiceContinue = confirm(message);
    },
    bind: function () {
        $.DirtyForms.choiceCommit($.Event("click"));
    },
    refire: function (content) {
        return false;
    },
    stash: function () {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms/tree/8e731503db5fe95a70700cf81295e5c7334fa253#dialog-example), the correct solution to use the browser dialog is to set the dialog to `false`.

```
$('form').dirtyForms();
$.DirtyForms.dialog = false;
```